# How can I make a clickable list in jquery where each item in the list is it own link not using HTML just jquery/ajax/json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I make a clickable list in jquery where each item in the list is its own link not using  HTML just jquery/ajax/json.

I need to make a clickable list in jquery.

what I need to do is to make it so that any user clicking on the list item runs an actual AJAX request.

I'm stuck on the on click function I create and i'm not sure what to do next

Do i need to add the JSON file to?

MY Javascript

```js
'use strict';

$(function() {
      $("#result-box").on("click", 'li', function() {
        console.log("#result-box");

      });


      let request = $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'people.json',
        dataType: 'json',
      });

      request.done(function(data) {
        let list = data.body.list;
        let resultBox = $('#result-box');
        let unorderedList = $('<ul>');
        resultBox.append(unorderedList);

        for (let person of list) {
          let listItem = $('<li>');
          listItem.text(person.name);
          listItem.attr('data-url', person.links[0].href);
          unorderedList.append(listItem);
        }

      });
```

```css
{
  "links":[ {
    "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people.json"
  }
  ,
  {
    "rel": "parent", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api.json"
  }
  ],
  "head": {
    "title": "People", "type":"listnav"
  }
  ,
  "body": {
    "list":[ {
      "name":"Adam",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/325.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Abigail Adams",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/157.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Adams",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/410.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Samuel Adams",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/439.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Charles Addams",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/1.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Aesculapius",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/127.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Richard Allen",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/169.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Saint Andrew",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/419.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Andrews",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/352.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Fra Angelico",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/278.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Maya Angelou",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/309.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Susan B. Anthony",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/158.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Apollo",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/312.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Cpl. Moses Arnold, Jr.",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/236.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Arthur Ashe",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/413.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Athena",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/234.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Atlas",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/401.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"William Wallace Atterbury",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/317.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Crispus Attucks",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/2.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Saint Augustine",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/265.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Bacchus",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/3.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Johann Sebastian Bach",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/4.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Rocky Balboa",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/5.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Matthias William Baldwin",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/6.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Ernesta Drinker Ballard",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/156.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Bartolommeo Bandinelli",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/277.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Felix Barbelin",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/210.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Albert Barnes",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/316.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Barry",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/7.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Josiah Bartlett",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/435.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Fra Bartolommeo",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/288.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Bartram",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/8.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Jasper Baxter",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/336.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"James A. Beaver",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/9.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Alexander Graham Bell",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/422.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Giovanni Bellini",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/269.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Cornelius F.J. Beukenkamp Jr.",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/396.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Julian Biddle",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/223.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"William W. Bodine, Jr.",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/122.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Anders Svennson Bonde",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/255.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Sgt. John J. Bonk, Jr.",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/237.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Pierre Bontemps",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/282.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Kevin Leah Bowser",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/337.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Aloysius Boyle",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/369.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Donato Bramante",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/296.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Samuel Livingston Breese",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/183.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Carrol Brenek",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/353.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Filippo Brunelleschi",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/300.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"William Cullen Bryant",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/214.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Charles J. Buckley",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/186.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Buddha",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/380.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Christian Bullitt",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/10.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Smedley D. Butler",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/173.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Alexander Milne Calder",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/172.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"James Caldwell",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/196.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Calliope",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/175.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"William Camac",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/11.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Ralph Campana",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/354.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Johan Campanius",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/249.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John J. Carlin",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/219.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Steve Carlton",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/12.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Hugo T. Caroselli",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/331.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Charles Carroll",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/13.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Carroll",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/125.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Bill Cash",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/177.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Lewis Cass",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/392.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Mary Cassat",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/14.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Octavius Catto",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/471.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Wilt Chamberlain",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/182.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"William Chance",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/321.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"James A. Chappell",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/231.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"King Charles II",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/263.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Samuel Chase",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/443.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Chief Joseph",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/162.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Abraham Clark",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/457.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Bobby Clarke",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/377.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Christopher Robert Clarke",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/338.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Henry Clay",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/394.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Roberto Clemente",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/204.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"George Clinton",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/440.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"George Clymer",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/452.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"James J. Cochran",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/387.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Peter Larsson Cock",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/252.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Rebecca Cole",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/15.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Sharonda Coleman-Singleton",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/424.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Coltrane",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/412.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Christopher Columbus",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/16.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"George Conor-Wood",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/206.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Meta Conor-Wood",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/207.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Russell Conwell",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/17.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Nicolaus Copernicus",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/19.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Correggio",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/295.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"S.W. Crawford",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/143.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Andrew Gregg Curtin",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/20.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Benedetto da Maiano",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/280.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Antonello da Messina",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/293.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/304.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Kim Dae-jung",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/264.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John A. B. Dahlgren",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/21.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Anders Larson Dalbo",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/253.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"David",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/328.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Samuel Davies",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/195.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Richard Foulke Day",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/224.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Eugene V. Debs",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/343.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Luca Della Robbia",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/281.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Demeter",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/187.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Richard F. Devine",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/200.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Arnolfo di Lapo",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/299.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Diana",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/22.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Charles Dickens",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/23.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Dickinson",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/451.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Richardson Dilworth",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/24.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Dionysus",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/400.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Fitz Eugene Dixon, Jr.",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/233.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Don Quixote",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/139.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Thomas Donahue",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/375.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Donatello",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/276.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Stephen A. Douglas",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/391.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Frederick Douglass",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/310.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Norton Downs, Jr.",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/225.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Anthony J. Drexel",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/25.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Katherine Drexel",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/409.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Drinkwater",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/221.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"W.E.B. Du Bois",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/307.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Mahlon Duckett",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/178.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Dr. Tanner G. Duckrey",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/339.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Hugh Duffy",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/322.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Albrecht Durer",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/305.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Mary Dyer",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/26.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Thomas Eakins",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/27.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Michael Francis Egan",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/408.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"William Ellery",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/450.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Erato",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/176.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"John Ericsson",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/28.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Julius Erving",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/29.json"
      }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "name":"Eve",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/326.json"
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <title>AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loaded-data"></div>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="result-box">
      <a></div>





</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you want to do , does this work for you  ?

```
listItem.click(function() {
  var url = $(this).data('url');
  makeAjaxRequest(url);
});


function makeAjaxRequest (url) {
      $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url ,
        dataType: 'json',
      });
}
```

Comment: I tried it now the people.json isn't appearing on the page